# Issue with ojdbc jar in Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, ojdbc

I've developed a project in Java 8 and I've installed the ojdbc jar in maven when I developed the project using java 8. Now I'm converting the project into java 7. While doing so, I'm facing issue with `ojdbc.jar` dependency in `pom.xml`. Its showing:

> Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0

at oracle dependency tag. When I try to run the mvn install for ojdbc jar, that also throws an error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SlotBookingAvailability: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.logicInfo.oms:SlotBookingAvailability:war:0.0.
>   1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 in https://repo.maven.a
>   pache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reat
>   tempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.logicInfo.oms</groupId>
<artifactId>SlotBookingAvailability</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SlotBookingAvailability</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


<properties>
    <start-class>org.logicInfo.oms.SlotBookingAvailability.SlotBookingAvailabilityApplication</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Can someone help me out of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with the answer of karol Dowbecki
I give you  more details for install
Download the jar from [oracle's website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)
Add ojdbc7.jar to the local maven repository.

Open cmd window

run comand: `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=G:/Jar/ojdbc7.jar`

change the jar name   location   version  to yours

then you will find  the jar in your maven local repository ,such as `${mavenrepository}/com/oracle/ojdbc7/${yourversion}/`

```
whdeMacBook-Pro:Downloads wh$ mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.newSpark:SparkLearn >-----------------------
[INFO] Building SparkLearn 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ SparkLearn ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/wh/Downloads/ojdbc7.jar to /server/mavenrepository/com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar
[INFO] Installing /var/folders/fc/23q8bt313pgbrxktr9f03ms80000gn/T/mvninstall7641723653608629745.pom to /server/mavenrepository/com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.564 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-04T14:33:34+08:00
[INFO] -----------------------------------
```

then  you can use your setting in your maven pom.xml

Comment: When i tried to run the above command to install the package, its throwing the below exception "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (default-cli) on project SlotBookingAvailability: Execution defa
ult-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file
 failed: 
ar:1.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1
.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.commons:commons-parent:pom:22 from/to
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2:Received fatal alert: protocol_
version"

Comment: Came to know its because of Java 7's TLSv1.2 issue, so tried to enable TLSv1.2. That also gives an exception because of missing ojdbc.jar "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SlotBookingAvailability: Could not res
olve dependencies for project org.logicInfo.oms:SlotBookingAvailability:war:0.0.
1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 in https://repo.maven.a
pache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reat
tempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -"

Comment: 'Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 in repo.maven.a pache.org/maven2',your jar file may has some problem  ,you  haven't intalled it  in your maven repository correctly

Answer (score 8):

Oracle JDBC drviers (`ojdbc6.jar`, `ojdbc7.jar`, `ojdbc8.jar`) are not published into Maven Central repository due to Oracle license. If it worked before you must have installed it locally (e.g. by running `mvn install:install-file`) or used a  repository other than Maven Central which had it.

You need to download the `ojdbc7` from Oracle website manually and agree to OTN License Agreement. Ideally you would download the `ojdbc7` JAR to match your Oracle Database server version (`SELECT * FROM v$version`).

Comment: I've downloaded the ojdbc7.jar manually from the Oracle site and added when i developed my application in java 8. Do i need to install again when i convert my application into java 7?

Comment: @Charan this will depend how will you set it up. If you install it locally with `mvn install:install-file` it will be available for all your local Maven projects.

Comment: Can you give the exact command to install the jar locally given my jar is place in C:\Users\pboobalan\Downloads\ojdbc?

Answer (score 0):

Please download the Oracle JDBC drivers from either [OTN](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html)  or you can download these from Oracle Maven repository (maven.oracle.com). Refer to the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) for instructions on downloading it from Oracle Maven.

Comment: I did, i'm getting exception while trying to add the jar in maven using mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\pboobalan\Downloads\ojdbc\ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar